# Importing photos from Windows PC to Photos

Tags: windows, photos, import, pc

I need to transfer all my picture collection, which is stored on a Windows PC, to a brand new Mac (Monterey)

On my PC, pictures are stored in folders, and correctly EXIF tagged (DateTimeOriginal), therefore, what I would like to achieve is to import pictures in Photos so that:

1. Albums are automatically created from the folder name
2. Albums are sorted automatically by picture EXIF dates, within an album
3. Pictures are automatically sorted by EXIF date (not by filesystem date or import date)

While point 1 can be apparently achieved using [this script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182493/photos-for-os-x-how-to-generate-album-automatically-at-import), how can I match point 2 & 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import photos from multiple/nested folders, open the Mac Photos app > in the top menu, click File > Import. Navigate to where your folders are, and select the top level folder which houses your complete folder hierarchy. Click "Review for Import", then check mark the "Keep Folder Organization" box. This will create an album for each folder. For nested folders, it will preserve the folders / albums hierarchy. Metadata will be preserved, so photos will appear in chronological order based on EXIF dates.